# Fantasy novel from the 90's. Maybe earlier. I can't remember the title

Tags: story-identification

At the beginning the villain is lured to a meeting where an attempt is made on his life. Another character fired a projectile out of a cane which wounded him but he was able to magic up a shield or something to avoid death.

There's also a bit later on where our protagonist (young male) has sex with a woman. There are elements of BDSM. She ties him up if I recall correctly.
I think him and his companions are guests at her home.

Comment: Hi we could really do with a bit more detail. I'd suggest you take the tour and learn how to improve your question. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate, but that's not a censure against you, just part of how we do bookkeeping. :) You will still get points for upvotes, people can still comment, etc. And yes, you can still accept your answer in another 44 hours or so.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out to be [***Tigana***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/104089.Tigana) by Guy Gavriel Kay, first published in 1990.

> Tigana is the magical story of a beleaguered land struggling to be free. It is the tale of a people so cursed by the black sorcery of a cruel despotic king that even the name of their once-beautiful homeland cannot be spoken or remembered...
>
> But years after the devastation, a handful of courageous men and women embark upon a dangerous crusade to overthrow their conquerors and bring back to the dark world the brilliance of a long-lost name...Tigana.

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the blurb into your answer

Comment: You will be able to self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour], but as a self-accept, you have to wait 48 hours from asking the question. But congrats! And welcome to the site.